# Custom Map Projection from a set of coordinates (no transformation/parameters available)

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, coordinates

I want to create a **Custom Map Projection in QGIS** without knowing any parameters for the transformation.

My basis is a georeferenced raster image that contains a grid with coordinates from a local system that has been used in some area in the 1960s. However, there is no known transformation for this local coordinate system. I could generate an image/dxf or even a list with more coordinates in both a known projection and the desired local system from AutoCAD, if it helps. The system only covers an area of about 3 by 3 kilometers and I only need any kind of accuracy inside this small area, because the system has never been used nor was it meant to be used outside it.

I cannot find much on the internet about this topic. I am neither a geography nor a GIS specialist, and so I have no idea how to approach this, though I figure there must be a way of calculating the transformation. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Couldn't you just digitize anything you need from the raster using a fitting UTM strip?

Comment: I get by with the UCS in CAD if I have to, as I have both the UTM strip and the local system there. The thing is, I want to add a bunch of different raster images using the same local system as grid in the QGIS project without first looking up all the coordinates in CAD. (But yeah, as a workaround I guess I could produce an image with the whole grid in 100m steps and use that as reference...)